# Understanding TaskManager and Task slot in the yarn environment

Tags: apache-flink

I am new  to Flink and haven't got a chance to read Flink source code to understand JobManager, TaskManager and Task Slot for the source code.

I have thought that TaskManager Process is like Spark's Executor Process, and JobManager is like Spark's Driver Process

But when I looks at the diagram https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/stream-processing-with/9781491974285/assets/components.png

It looks that my thought is wrong? It is the Task Slot process that runs in the YARN container? That is, Task Slot is similar to Spark's executor process.

I don't have a good or clear understanding about JobManager、TaskManager and TaskSlot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/concepts/runtime.html#job-managers-task-managers-clients) explains how the distributed runtime is organized. To summarize roughly, in comparison to Spark:

- Task Manager: Spark Worker
- Task Slot: Spark Task
- Application: Spark Driver Program

As for Flink's Job Manager, until fairly recently (Flink 1.6) this was a monolith playing many roles. Now that it has been refactored it remains responsible for most cluster-wide concerns that are independent of the cluster framework -- meaning things like coordinating checkpoints and recovery, and scheduling.

See also the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197744/confused-about-flink-task-slot).

Comment: Thanks @avid-anderson for the good answer. I wonder why Flink introduces this concept-TaskSlot.My understanding is that TaskSlot is just a thread in TM that actually runs the task logic.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610342/difference-between-job-and-task-in-flink/53620443#53620443